# How to change background color of table in code behind?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I want to change the background color of a table whose table tag is inside HeaderTemplate in Asp:Repeater.
how can I do this?

Comment: I gave you some nice answers in your previous queries. I think. You should check it, If possible accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

### Sample HTML

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="header" style="background:green;" runat="server">
                    textBox
                </td>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="ed" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

### Sample Code Behind

```
protected void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
    {
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell cell = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell)e.Item.FindControl("header");
        cell.BgColor = "Red";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write the necessary CSS and apply it using the CssClass property, or you could manually set it using the .Style["background"] 'property'.

Comment: I m not able to access the table id because my <table> tag is inside header template in Repeater and i can't write runat="server" in <table> tag.So how can i access the table id and set its properties like style .

Comment: Is there any solution to this?

Comment: I don't have any experience with the repeater control I'm afraid